# Limited devices Login's like Netflix

Tags: authentication

I am trying to build a video streaming platform and I need to implement a limited devices login feature just like netflix. I have seen some people using [node device detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-device-detector) to get the device type from the useragent, but I don't think this is a good solution since the user agent can be faked. Please any ideas on how to effectively implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my own answer, I can use fingerprint.js to identify devices and store in mongodb. and I found an open source version for fingerprint.js that is [broprint.js](https://github.com/Rajesh-Royal/Broprint.js)

Comment: Actually, FingerprintJS is open source: https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs